# How do I use custom fonts in React - Native 0.64, iOS does, but Android doesn't

Tags: android, fonts, react-native

I configured it according to this method [Link](https://medium.com/@gattermeier/custom-fonts-in-react-native-for-android-b8a331a7d2a7#.w6aok6lpw) , but it doesn't work for Android.

My font file is named: din_alternate_bold.ttf
This is what I use in RN's style: `fontFamily: 'DIN Alternate Bold'` & `fontFamily: 'DIN_Alternate_Bold'`  & `fontFamily: 'din alternate bold'` & `fontFamily: 'din_alternate_bold'` None of these ways work.

What should I configure to use Android custom fonts in RN?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of things has been changed since React Native 0.60+ and there is now autolinking enabled by default, the Manual method sometimes throw error all you need to do is:

1. create folder in root of your project, assets.
2. inside that assets folder create fonts folder.
3. paste your fonts inside that folder.
4. create file named react-native.config.js in the root directory of your project.
   paste these codes in react-native.config.js file.

> module.exports = {   project: {
> ios: {},
> android: {},   },   assets: ['./assets/fonts'], };

5. now run npx react-native link

and use the fonts as you are using in fontFamily: 'yourfont_name',

Comment: That's what I did. But it doesn't work with Android. :(

Comment: Can you share a piece of code where are you using it and also the name of the file?

Comment: Also please verify that the name of the font which are inside assets are the same you are using in your styling

Comment: If all of the above are checked run command cd ./android && ./gradlew clean and then again run npx react-native run-android

Comment: The name in Android assets/font is din_alternate_bold.ttf, and when I used it, I tried several ways：1. `fontFamily: 'din_alternate_bold'` 2.`fontFamily: 'DIN Alternate Bold'`3.`fontFamily: 'DIN-Alternate-Bold'`

Comment: The font file is `din_alternate_bold.ttf` ，. Which is the correct notation in the style file. thx

Comment: there are two posibilities now:
1) The font files are not in present in the folder project\android\app\src\main\assets\fonts;
 If the files are present in the above folder, then move to the 2nd step.

2) The bundle is not synced with the new files,
   To solve this, open terminal in your project root, run cd ./android && ./gradlew clean;
   After this connect your android device or if you are using the emulator simply run the command npx react-native run-android;

   If all above are not working, please provide your React Native version.

Answer (score 0):

if you run the `npx react-native link` and it did not work on android, you need to copy the fonts and paste them on `android/src/main/assets/fonts/` then on command line write `npx react-native run-android`

Comment: I'm sure I already have a font file in my assets/fonts  folder, but Android just can't use fonts

Comment: did you checked if the pure android project can recognize the font? i mean build an android project and used that font on that project if it didn't worked perhaps there is something wrong about the font. maybe it contain capital letter or some symbol that you missed

Answer (score 0):

**Clean gradle and make sure you put the exact name of your .ttf file.**

First from the root of the project:

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
```

Then call it with the exact name of your .ttf file

```
<Text style={{fontFamily: 'exactNameOfTheDownloadedFont'}}> Hello </Text>
```